# Imbalanced dataset doesn't produce good 'Precision' or 'Recall'

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

The dataset is extremely imbalanced the positive results were only 10% approximately compared to negative results. Eg: (0 - 11401, 1- 1280).

I have tried
1. `RandomForestClassifier` with `GridSearchCV` - hyper parameter tuning.
2. Weighted RandomForest with `class_weight="balanced"`
3. Penalised `SVC`
4. UpSampling and DownSampling

Still I don't get good precision or recall in any of the above methods.
Im aware prevalence is related PPV. And my dataset has very low class -1. Also Random Forest may lean to majority class.

But i was hoping sampling should work but it didn't. Am I missing something? Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: added form code formatting

Answer (score 1):

a few methodes should help you:

- predict probabilities and do a manual thresholding.
- change the loss/metric you are using.
- for an imbalance dataset (outliers detection) you shoudln't use class_weight=balance but put more weight on the outliers.
- try other algorithm to see if some do better (XGBoost,catboost,lightgbm if you want to stick with tree based solutions)
- we can also use tpot to find the best algo in sklearn for your particular dataset

tell me if any of those helped you

Comment: Many thanks  for quick response.  i will try and let you know.  For ROC i use predict probability but i didn't do manual threshold. I tried class-weight:{0:1,1:100} in SVC that didnt work  . i will try in RF aswell.